# slow select in (...) (springdata jpa in mysql )

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, redis

I have a table "A", "A" has a Column `AreaId`, When I `select * from "A"`, I wanna show results where AreaId in my account.
Other, I hava a table "B",it means I hava some AreaIds, It possible thousands or hundreds.
So, When I select from A , I will `select * from A where areaId in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7.....1000)`,it is too slow
How can I solve this, Thank you

Now I use in(.....) and redis, but it too slow

---

```
public class UserArea

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Integer uid;

    @Column(name = "areaId")
    private Integer aid;


public class PotentialUser implements AbstractBas {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "areaId")
    protected Integer aid;
}
```

this is my A and B Table , one user possible hava 1000+ areas

Comment: use subquery, and make sure you have index on `B.areaId`

Comment: Are the numbers necessarily consecutive?  `(1,2,3,4,...)`

Comment: Did you try a `JOIN`?  That should worm much better than extracting the ids and building an `IN` list.

Comment: the numbers is random, possible (1,5,50,201,.....)

Comment: I have tried Join and subquery, but it is slow too, Too many parameters

Comment: Now I use redis, I save Table B to Redis ,It faster than before,But When I use redis , I cannot use Join and subquery

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `areaId` field has an index

With the `in` keyword, the index cannot be hit when there are a large number of matching values ​​following it.

If those matching values ​​are consecutive, use the following statement：

```
select * from A where areaId >= 1 and areaId <= 1000
```

By the way, in your question, what exactly does Table B do?
You only gave how table A is used.I don't know, what exactly are you trying to do with Form B.

### Update at 230228

The field type needs to be a number type to ensure that the index is taken when using greater than or less than

Comment: I have tried this, but this way is like " in (...)", it also not use index， when the parameters >2,  it will not use index

Comment: In fact, I have a total of 4 tables: Table A represents records, Table B represents the relationship between accounts and regions, Table C represents regions, and Table D represents accounts. One account may have permissions for several hundred regions, which are reflected in Table B. When I query Table A, I need to use the aid field in Table A to filter whether this account has corresponding regional permissions.